# having proplems with JokeAPI js

Tags: javascript, api, npm

My code:

```js
const JokeAPI = require('sv443-joke-api');
let x;
JokeAPI.getJokes().then((res) => res.json()).then((joke) => {x = joke;})
console.log(x.includes(joke)?x.joke:`Q: ${x.startup} A: ${x.delivery}`))
```

I did `npm install --save sv443-joke-api` before running, my problem is that it gives me an error when I logged it at the console.
the error:

```
console.log(x.includes(joke)?x.joke:`Q: ${x.startup} A: ${x.delivery}`)
                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

Comment: Where do you log it?

Comment: I log it to the console

Comment: I mean in your code. Because `getJokes()` looks asynchronous. Could you put your `console.log()` in the example too?

Comment: the error is because you are trying to read the result of asynchronous operation before its finished executing, I suggest you move those `console.log` statements into the `then` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's not the API that has problems :)

```js
const jokeHtml = (item) => {
  return `
    <div class="single-joke">
      Category: ${item.category}<br />
      Joke:<br />
      ${item.joke}
    </div>
  `
};

const jokeList = (items) => {
  return items.map(item => jokeHtml(item))
}

(async function() {
  const response = await fetch('https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any?blacklistFlags=nsfw,religious,political,racist,sexist,explicit&type=single&amount=2')
  const json = await response.json()
  document.getElementById('jokelist').innerHTML = jokeList(json.jokes).join('')
})();
```

```css
.single-joke {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="jokelist"></div>
```